# Term for Entrance fee

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

I am about to "invent" an [extension to the iCalendar MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Calendar_extensions).

A calendar event may be one, where you need to pay money to get in. Since there is no such thing already defined in any RFC, I will go ahead and use my own form. But in case this takes off and everyone wants to have it, it would be good to come up with a proper term in the first place. So I am wondering, what's the most appropriate term therefore, according to most general usage and international meaning. Here are some terms, I found so far:

- `X-ENTRANCE-FEE`
- `X-ENTRY-FEE`
- `X-ADMISSION`
- `X-ADMITTANCE`

Any other suggestions are welcome, of course.

Comment: What about just "Fee?"

Comment: Welcome to English.SE! Is this more of a programming question than an English usage question?

Comment: Please note that requests for help with naming (including things like variables or database columns) are explicitly off-topic; anything can be a legitimate label and so which is the "right" answer tends to come down to opinion. In general, requests for suggestions, tips, recommendations, or other open-ended lists are not well-suited to the Stack Exchange Q&A format. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of the first two.

*Admission* and *admittance* are less optimal than *entry fee* or *entrance fee* because there may be other criteria besides money going into admission or admittance. For instance, for a group meeting, being the member of a group may lead to someone being given admission or admittance. (I could also imagine confusion with other meanings of admission, like being enrolled at a university.)

In the Oxford English Dictionary, [*entry fee*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/63014) and [*entrance fee*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62944) are virtually interchangeable and common to American and British English. I haven't found a better equivalent; I've heard of having to pay "at the door," but it's not like *door-money* is a popular or well-recognized term.

Answer (score 0):

*"need to pay money to get in"* is reminiscent of card games where the common term is ante

So in a similar case you could try your hand and propose X-ANTE
Which has a double meaning see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ex-ante
where one example usage is
"In contrast, ex ante funds are preferable when firms have enough capital "

Wiki defines it as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex-ante

"The term ex-ante (sometimes written ex ante or exante) is a phrase meaning "before the event".
and gives as an example the fee for a lottery entry.